# Oracle Query design

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables joining with left outer join

**Employee**

```
Employeed_Id    Employee_Name   Location_id

1               David           1
2               Andrew          2
3               Mike            3
4               steve           4
```

**Employee_profile**

```
profile_id     profile_name   location_id  profile_location
1              manager           1          NYC
2              accountant        2          Jersey
3              engineer          1          Mexico
4              trainer           3           Boston
```

This is the common query I have to retrieve the all employees based on location.here profile_location is unique.

Problem is, in some part of the application profile_location is not required. So Outer join between above tables is not required.

How to develop a query, so it should function normally in case of profile_location not have input value with outer join.

**Below is my Query:**

```
select e.Employee_Name 
from Employee e,
     Employee_profile ep 
 where e.location_id (+) = ep.location_id
 and ep.profile_location='xxxxx'
```

Comment: please don't use implict joins in the where clause. Use an explicit `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - please don't bang on about ANSI joins.  They're cool, but can cause problems with Oracle's optimizer.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Do you want to return the records that are equal to `profile_location` but also return records if that value doesn't exist?

Comment: Hi,How it solve my problem?

Comment: @APC: do you have an **proof** for that? I know there were problems in 8i, and 9i but not in any recent/current version.

Comment: @bluefeet:any help on this issue.

Comment: @user1861226 Can you expand on your sample data and then post the desired result of your query?

Comment: @bluefeet:if query based on 'profile_location' value 'NYC' then it should return David.That is already covered,if i dont give anything on it should return all employees.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'd be very surprised if there were any issues with ANSI joins in 8i as Oracle didn't introduce them until 9i :)  As for proof, I'll submit an example from Jonathan Lewis : http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/ansi-argh/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return those records that match your passed in `profile_location` but also want to return all records when the location does not exist, then you can use something like this:

```
select distinct e."Employee_Name"
from Employee e
left join Employee_profile ep 
  on e."Location_id" = ep."location_id"
where ep."profile_location" = 'xxx'
    or not exists (select ep1."profile_location" 
                   from Employee_profile ep1
                   where  ep1."profile_location" = 'xxx')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64369/31)

If you pass in a value that does not exist like `'xxx'` the result is:

```
| EMPLOYEE_NAME |
-----------------
|         David |
|        Andrew |
|         steve |
|          Mike |
```

If you pass in `'NYC'` the result is:

```
| EMPLOYEE_NAME |
-----------------
|         David |
```

Comment: thanks,it not solves my problem,it should return records those passed condition e.location_id  = ep.location_id,if profile_location not present

Comment: @User I think you mean, if profile_location is NULL (not present), you only need to match the condition `e.location_id = ep.location_id`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.Employee_Name 
from Employee e,
     Employee_profile ep 
 where e.location_id (+) = ep.location_id
 and (ep.profile_location='xxxxx'
   Or ep.profile_location is null)
```

Comment: Even this query  not returning anything because there is no values present with null